# Normalmap makes everything shiny and causes issues

Tags: baking, normal-map, reflection

when i bake a Normalmap in Blender and use it, it makes the whole mesh shiny and reflective and
creates other issues like visable seams/patches.
Not at first but after renaming it or using a copy of the same normal map, then the issue becomes visable.

Even if use a random asset that i did not make myself and replace one of its normal maps with the same, just renamed normal map, it creats the issues.

They also appear when I import the Mesh and Textures into an gameengine like UE4.
That makes me wonder if there are informations in the mesh or textures that cause this problem.
Some settings i have missed in Blender?

Thank you for your help

https://postimg.cc/gallery/Zq76bbv Images

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: In your screenshots, the _Image Texture_ node with the renamed normal map is set to _Color Space_ > _sRGB_ whereas the original is set to _Non-Color_. Maybe try changing that. That's the only difference I see, but I'm no expert in baking normal maps.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann is right, but notice also your 3rd pic: the same normal map is non-color, not sRGB-- it changed.  I've noticed bugs with Blender changing the color space of images on or soon after baking, but couldn't reproduce for a report, so be careful of your color space.  Bake and use a normal map in non-color, verify before and after baking.

Answer (score 0):

mayby it was just baked wrong, I've had the same issue until I noticed I baked the normal map using a image texture node that was set to sRGB. When I plugged the normal map in my model with the image texture set to "non-color" (as one always should since its not using the map for its color but for its vector information) it shaded my object super shiny and the seems would be visible in some places.

My fix was simply to rebake the normal map using an image texture set to "non-color".

I don't know if that's what's causing your issue, I've seen it several times and it always seems to sort itself out by tweeking... never knew what caused it.